# Win32 window - no close message

Tags: c++, winapi

I am currently making a small win32 window wrapper class, but I have a few problem.
If I hit the close(X) button of the window the window closes immediately without sending a quit or destroy message, so I can't for example prevent the window to close or save something before closing the window.
And the second problem/question is,
If I use this small code to use the window, the computer cpu gets strongly used.
But its only a small window.
How I can change/fix this?

```
int main()
{
    glwCreate();
    while(true/*Later here comes a method that checks, wether window close is requested*/)
    {
        glwUpdate();
    }
    glwDestroy();

    return 0;
}
```

-

```
#include "glw.h"


#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>


HINSTANCE instanceHandle;
WNDCLASSEX windowClass;
HWND windowHandle;


LRESULT CALLBACK WindowMessageHandler(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    std::cout<<uMsg<<'\n';

    switch(uMsg)
    {
        case WM_QUIT:
        {
            std::cout<<"QUIT\n";
            return 0;
        }
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            std::cout<<"DESTROY\n";
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return (DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam));
}


void glwCreate()
{
    instanceHandle = GetModuleHandle(0);

    windowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    windowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    windowClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowMessageHandler;
    windowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    windowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    windowClass.hInstance = instanceHandle;
    windowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(0,IDC_ARROW);
    windowClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
    windowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    windowClass.lpszClassName = "atomus_window_class";
    windowClass.lpszMenuName = "menu_name";
    windowClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
    RegisterClassEx(&windowClass);

    windowHandle = CreateWindowEx(  0,
                                    "atomus_window_class",
                                    "atomus title",
                                    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                    CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    instanceHandle,
                                    0);

    ShowWindow(windowHandle, SW_SHOW);
}
void glwDestroy()
{
    DestroyWindow(windowHandle);
    windowHandle = 0;

    UnregisterClass(windowClass.lpszClassName, instanceHandle);
}
void glwUpdate()
{
    MSG message;
    while (PeekMessage (&message, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) > 0) //Or use an if statement
    {
         TranslateMessage (&message);
         DispatchMessage (&message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear for now. Please highlight the relevant code.

Comment: Why does it seem that everyone who tries a simple window handler uses PeekMessage instead of GetMessage?  Do they not notice a whole core being used up for nothing?

Comment: You don't get WM_QUIT when you don't call PostQuitMessage().  It should *not* be handled by the window procedure, the window isn't there anymore.  Needs to be done in the game loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add handling for `WM_CLOSE` you get to control whether your window closes or not. By not providing your own handling for that message you get the default from `DefWindowProc` which is to destroy your window.